# GeoServer REST API | Unable to get records more than 100 records

Tags: geoserver-rest-api, geoserver-monitor

I have deployed GeoServer 2.18.0 under Tomcat 9 on CentOS along with installed Monitor extension as well.

Accessing monitoring data using REST API and getting that data, but only 100 rows I can see.

[image: GeoServer REST API]

I checked the following :

- GeoServer REST API limitation
- Web Server setting
- Data is available more than 1000 rows

Unable to figure out this issue. How can I GWT more than 100 rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the configuration documentation: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/monitoring/configuration.html

you will see that it mentions the following:

> Memory Storage
>
> With memory storage only the most recent 100 requests
> are stored. And by definition this storage is volatile in that if the
> GeoServer instance is restarted, shutdown, or crashes this data is
> lost.

So the solution seems to be to save the data in a database, using the hibernate option.

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/monitor-hibernate/db.html#monitor-db